# Crostini View Localhost On Another Computer

Tags: google-chrome-os, crostini

I want to run a live server on crostini and access it on another computer so I can see the website as I develop it. How can I accomplish this? Is there a way I can expose localhost as long as I’m on the same WiFi?

Answer (score 1):

No. `localhost` is local to the container.

You will need to persuade the server you are using to bind to the container's external interface.

How to do that depends on the software you are trying to use.

For hugo it would look like:

```
hugo server --bind `hostname -I` --baseURL `hostname -I`
```

But that only gets you to the chromebook itself, to make it visible outside *that* you will need to use a [port forwader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/connection-forwarder/ahaijnonphgkgnkbklchdhclailflinn)

There is some information in my [blog post](https://www.codevamping.com/2018/11/chromeos-linux-tips/#viewing-local-servers)